# Notepad ++ complex pattern search

Tags: notepad++, regex

Hi i'm looking for a notepad++ regex pattern match in a text, and bring some replacements. But so far what I have come up with does not seem to work.

Sample text:

```
1 blablablabla. blablnsnsnns, blalblblbl: blablaa; balal blala. 2 blblb'blbµµ77777µµlblb blblb, blslsµµ105µµnlsllsl.
3 blalblblbl: blablaa; balal blala. 4 blblb'blbµµ9999µµlblb . Blblb, blslsnlsllsl. 5 jsjjsjj; gggbqbqbq:   ghshhqhhqh !. Gsgsjjsskksk. 6 fshhhshs, nnsnnsns! nsnnsn. 7 blalallallal7600hhzhz ; nmmkzjzbzbzb34fspmmm :
blslslslsavccacac,
hkkdlfmfmmf56balalala.
hdfmmfm87kdkkkkfkf.
8 blalalallajhshduie.
9 bslslslslls :
blslsllsllls,
bslslllsllsls.
nsnsnnsnsnnsnns,
hsbbbslslsllsllsls.
10 bslsllsllsllsllslls à sbsbbsbbsb , snsnnsnnsnnsn.
```

Pattern search:
I'm looking for the beginning of any number followed by a space and some texts and stops before the next number preceded by a space is encountered.

grouping should look like:

- groupe 1 : a number
- groupe 2 : the space character following the number
- groupe 3 : some text which can also include some numbers but these numbers are not between space characters,instead they are between (µµ) .

Expected results:

```
<VERSETAG=1>blablablabla. blablnsnsnns, blalblblbl: blablaa; balal blala.</VERSETAG>
<VERSETAG=2> blblb'blbµµ77777µµlblb blblb, blslsµµ105µµnlsllsl.</VERSETAG>
<VERSETAG=3>blalblblbl: blablaa; balal blala.</VERSETAG>
<VERSETAG=4>blblb'blbµµ9999µµlblb . Blblb, blslsnlsllsl.</VERSETAG>
<VERSETAG=5>jsjjsjj; gggbqbqbq:   ghshhqhhqh !. Gsgsjjsskksk.</VERSETAG>
<VERSETAG=6>fshhhshs, nnsnnsns! nsnnsn.</VERSETAG>
<VERSETAG=7>blalallallal7600hhzhz ; nmmkzjzbzbzb34fspmmm :
blslslslsavccacac,
hkkdlfmfmmf56balalala.
hdfmmfm87kdkkkkfkf.</VERSETAG>
<VERSETAG=8>blalalallajhshduie.</VERSETAG>
<VERSETAG=9>bslslslslls :</VERSETAG>
<VERSETAG=10>bslsllsllsllsllslls à sbsbbsbbsb , snsnnsnnsnnsn.</VERSETAG>
```

Tested with this Regex thanks to @Toto (but so far not working as expected, see result bellow):

```
Look for :
(?:^\D*|\G )(\d+)\s+(.+?)\R?(?=\s\d+\s|\z) 

replace with :
<VERSETAG=$1>$2</VERSETAG>\n
```

Result of the test :

```
<VERSETAG=1>blablablabla. blablnsnsnns, blalblblbl: blablaa; balal blala.</VERSETAG>
 2 blblb'blbµµ77777µµlblb blblb, blslsµµ105µµnlsllsl.
<VERSETAG=3>blalblblbl: blablaa; balal blala.</VERSETAG>
<VERSETAG=4>blblb'blbµµ9999µµlblb . Blblb, blslsnlsllsl.</VERSETAG>
<VERSETAG=5>jsjjsjj; gggbqbqbq:   ghshhqhhqh !. Gsgsjjsskksk.</VERSETAG>
<VERSETAG=6>fshhhshs, nnsnnsns! nsnnsn.</VERSETAG>
 7 blalallallal7600hhzhz ; nmmkzjzbzbzb34fspmmm :
blslslslsavccacac,
hkkdlfmfmmf56balalala.
hdfmmfm87kdkkkkfkf.
8 blalalallajhshduie.
9 bslslslslls :
<VERSETAG=10>bslsllsllsllsllslls à sbsbbsbbsb , snsnnsnnsnnsn.</VERSETAG>
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Could you tell us, in words, what your pattern is supposed to achieve?

Comment: Hi,As described in the expected result:
When it finds a number that is followed by a space , it should put a tag there with that number inside the (<VERSETAG=1>) and before encountering the next number followed by a space, it should put the closing tag.(</VERSETAG>)

Comment: I just run with your new test case, it works pretty fine. Have you checked `. matches newline`?

Comment: Yes Indeed now working perfectly!! Awesome ! Great help !

Answer (score 2):

Update according to comments:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^\D*|\G )(\d+)\s+(.+?)\R?(?=\s\d+\s|\z)`
- Replace with: `<VERSETAG=$1>$2</VERSETAG>\n`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:^\D*|\G )    # non capture group, beginning of line followed by 0 or more non digits  or restart from the last match position
(\d+)           # group 1, 1 or more digits
\s+             # 1 or more spaces
(.+?)           # group 2, 1 or more any character including new line, not greedy
\R?             # any kind of linebreak, optional
(?=\s\d+\s|\z)  # positive lookahead, make sure we have after 1 or more digits surround with spaces or end of file
```

**Result for given example:**

```
<VERSETAG=1>blablablabla. blablnsnsnns, blalblblbl: blablaa; balal blala.</VERSETAG>
<VERSETAG=2>blblb'blbµµ77777µµlblb blblb, blslsµµ105µµnlsllsl.</VERSETAG>
<VERSETAG=3>blalblblbl: blablaa; balal blala.</VERSETAG>
<VERSETAG=4>blblb'blbµµ9999µµlblb . Blblb, blslsnlsllsl.</VERSETAG>
<VERSETAG=5>jsjjsjj; gggbqbqbq:   ghshhqhhqh !. Gsgsjjsskksk.</VERSETAG>
<VERSETAG=6>fshhhshs, nnsnnsns! nsnnsn.</VERSETAG>
<VERSETAG=7>blalallallal7600hhzhz ; nmmkzjzbzbzb34fspmmm:
blslslslsavccacac,
hkkdlfmfmmf56balalala.
hdfmmfm87kdkkkkfkf.</VERSETAG>
<VERSETAG=8>blalalallajhshduie.</VERSETAG>
```

Capture screen

[image]

Comment: **Awesome Toto! We are almost there! but it seems not to be working when the line starts with some texts:**

`For example, the followin is not working :` 

`1 blablablabla. blablnsnsnns, blalblblbl: blablaa; balal blala. 2 blblb'blbµµ77777µµlblb blblb, blslsµµ105µµnlsllsl.
3 blalblblbl: blablaa; balal blala. 4 blblb'blbµµ9999µµlblb . Blblb, blslsnlsllsl. 5 jsjjsjj; gggbqbqbq:   ghshhqhhqh !. Gsgsjjsskksk. 6 fshhhshs, nnsnnsns! nsnnsn.
dlflflf4532llflflf, vjjsjsjss8776nndndn54; qcqaataab. 7 hhhshhshhshhshhshhs, bslslslsllslsllsll.`

Comment: @Pmicezjk: just replace `(?:^|\G )` with `(?:^\D*|\G )` at the beginning of regex. See my edit.

Comment: `Still not working between (check around versetag 7 and 8). This is what I got when I replace (?:^|\G ) with (?:^\D*|\G )` :

`<VERSETAG=7>blalallallal7600hhzhz ; nmmkzjzbzbzb34fspmmm:</VERSETAG>

blslslslsavccacac,
hkkdlfmfmmf56balalala.
hdfmmfm87kdkkkkfkf.
<VERSETAG=8>blalalallajhshduie.</VERSETAG>`

Comment: I did exactly what you said : just replace (?:^|\G ) with (?:^\D*|\G ).

 In one sample text, I have no tags when the lines starts with some texts.
In the other sample text I have the line that starts with a text completely vanished.

Comment: @Pmicezjk: I've completly rewrite the regex, not just add `\D*`

Comment: `I have tried the last remedy :`
`Find what: (?:^\D*|\G )(\d+)\s+(.+?)\R?(?=\s\d+\s|\z)`
`Replace with: <VERSETAG=$1>$2</VERSETAG>\n`

`But some lines which start with numbers are no longer working as previously! And it's not better when the lines start with some text.
`

Comment: @Pmicezjk: Sorry, I don't get you, it seems working for me. Have you Checked `. matches newline`? Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1374975/edit) and add some input lines that don't work for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85708/discussion-between-pmicezjk-and-toto).

Comment: @Pmicezjk: Feel free to marck answer as accepted, see: https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers